# Saving the array.length to a variable in order to manipulate the latter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good day everyone,

I am fairly new to working with vue.js and unfortunately don't have anyone in my environment which I could ask for help. Currently I am trying to fix a few bugs in an existing project and got stuck on a rather simple task.

My current fix is aiming to reduce the variable that saves an array.length after a @click of a button has been made.
I've already established the connection between the child and parent components and am now looking to somehow save the array.length in a variable to then reduce/increase it everytime the button is clicked.

The attempts to declare the variable in props or data did not show the expected result so far.

**tl;dr:** I want to declare *var a = this.allRootItems.length;* somewhere in the code in order to manipulate it in the method *calcDeduction()* in order to display it through the prop function *heading()*. The current code does not seem to solve that.

A few snippets of the relevant code (I am able to provide more if necessary):

```js
data() {
    return {
      showItems: false,
      progress: 0,
      a: 0,
    };


computed: {
  ...
  heading() {
    var a = this.allRootItems.length;
    var text = this.section.heading+" ("+this.progress+"/"+a+")";
    return text;
  },
  ...

  allRootItems() {
      var result = [];
      if (this.checklistid==null) {
        return result;
      }
      var rootItems = this.findRootItemsInStore({ query:{
        sectionId: this.section.id
      } }).data;
      for (var i=0; i<rootItems.length; i++) {
        var itemToDo = this.findCheckItemsInStore({ query:{
          checklistId: this.checklistid,
          rootitemId: rootItems[i].id
        } }).data[0];
        if (itemToDo) {
          if (itemToDo.isTodo) {
            result.push(rootItems[i]);
          }
        }
       }
      return result;
     },
  ...

methods: {
  ...
  calcDeduction(dedValue) {
      if (dedValue==-1) { //-1 and 1 are being swapped on each toggle of the button
        this.a--;
      }
      if (dedValue==1) {
        this.a++;
      }
      console.log(this.a);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.a` is never set to `this.allRootItems.length`, is this on purpose? It only gets increased/decreased at `calcDeduction()`. In other words, you are setting the Length to a local variable `a` but always using `this.a` for displaying in the text in `heading()`.

Comment: Hey, it was not on purpose, It was a typo.

Comment: Shouldn't this solve your issue, or am i missing something from your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have 2 different a, one that is being declared in data() and the second is the var inside heading computed. To avoid confusion, I suggest you lose the a inside heading

And second try to set a to the length inside allRootItems after calculatig the result

```
this.a = result.length
return result;
```

and keep this.a inside text

Comment: As `allRootItems` is a computed property, i wouldn't suggest manipulating data properties inside. I would rather recommend to create if possible a `setup()` or `created()` hook to initialize `this.a` as soon as possible.

Comment: @IISkullsII agreed! but i'm not exactly sure about the desired behavior, maybe he would like a to keep up to date with the array

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I got a bit confused. It worked.

And both of you are right, I probably should not resolve the issue with such a solution, but I just started learning about js and vue.js and am therefore sticking to the basics I know for now.

Comment: cool ! but pay attention to the first comment. if you dont want a to keep updating every time allRootItems is called, you should initialise a in a lifecycle, set it to the array length, and then update it with the button